# How to get OAuth2 authorization code for google signin swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, google-signin

How to get OAuth2 authorization code in google signin for swift 4.

trying to get using the variable
// An OAuth2 authorization code for the home server.
@property(nonatomic, readonly) NSString *serverAuthCode;
but returning nil value.

Answer (score 0):

We need to add both ID in AppDelegate didFinishLaunchingWithOptions 
GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().clientID        = "XXX" 
GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().serverClientID  = "XXX"